# What is this below the schedule and how do I disable it?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have attached a picture of my fullcalendar view and wonder if I can remove the highlighted part underneath the schedule, and how to do that.

Code:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap' ],
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotDuration: '01:00:00',
    minTime: '09:00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00:00',
    nowIndicator: true,
    locale: 'dk',
    timeZone: 'local',
    firstDay: 1,
    weekNumbers: true,
    weekLabel: "Uge",
    columnHeaderFormat: {
        weekday: 'long',
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric',
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: 'i dag',
        month: 'måned',
        week: 'uge',
        day: 'dag'
    },
    events: [
        {
            title: 'ROCKETMAN',
            start: '2019-11-07',
            end: '2019-11-07'
        }
    ]
});
```

[image: fullcalendar - highlighted content needs to be removed]

Comment: please try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add some code what ever you have tried so far.

Comment: show us your code, please.

Comment: Did you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing and try anything? What settings have you got currently? Here's a simple version using the height setting which I think would help you: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ydwjmV

Comment: I've added my code - the only code I really have is the initializing code with settings

Comment: That's fine...that's the important information. Glad the height option helped you. Remember to always read the documentation in detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set the height to auto:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap' ],
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    height: 'auto'
});
```